# Total Amount not displaying in contribution price set in Joomla 3

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contribution-page, price-sets

I have seen this issue in a couple other posts, but none that had an answer that applied to me.

I have CiviCRM 5.5.2, Joomla 3.8 and the RocketTheme Notio template. I have upgraded from a much older setup. In this updated build, the total amount doesn't display in my online form. In the backend preview, it displays and works just fine. On the website, not so much. I get the "Total Amount" label, but nothing for content.

Ideas of what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be JS errors on browser console. Since the total amount is calculated using javascript. If you see JS errors check

1. Directory path in CiviCRM
2. Resource URL 
   3 Cleanup CiviCRM Cache

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The resource URL was the source of the issue. Thanks!